# Remote Stylesheet Paths

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a stylesheet

http://remoteserver/stylesheet.css

```
body {
    background-image: url('/images/bgimage.jpg');
}
```

located in the head of a local document

http://localserver/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="http://remoteserver/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1> This is a test </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Which image would get loaded:-

http://remoteserver/images/bgimage.jpg

or

http://localserver/images/bgimage.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the paths in the css were always relative to the css file.
So it would load.

http://remoteserver/images/bgimage.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It would be the **remote Server**.
The reason for this is because in the CSS file, you're using `url('/images/bgimage.jpg');` which is referring to the images folder within the remote server relative to the directory of the CSS file.
If you want it to load the image on the local Server, you will have to write something like this: 
`url('http://localserver/images/bgimage.jpg');`
 which will refer to the image file within the local Server.

Comment: I think he's saying that the CSS file stored on another Server is referring to an image stored on that Server, but he wants it to be for his own.